# Sampling high dimensional vectors with uniform angle

Tags: random, sampling

A sample of randomly drawn vectors are mostly perpendicular in high dimensions, as per [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/995623/why-are-randomly-drawn-vectors-nearly-perpendicular-in-high-dimensions). This makes sense to me.

I have a problem where given one point $v$ in $n$ dimensions, I need to sample $m$ points $\{u_i\}, \quad i=1,...,m$  such that the distribution of the angle between each $u_i$ and $v$ is uniform over $(0, \pi)$.

A simple approach would just be to fix the first $n-1$ dimensions and sample the last dimension to give the desired uniform distribution. If I want my samples to be random over every dimension, what other approaches can I take?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They *cannot* be "random over every dimension".  To get uniformity in angular distribution, you will have to add a relation.

You don't say what you want to do with the magnitudes.  All the same as $|v|$?  Random with some distribution?  Something else?  Consequently, I describe how to get all unit magnitudes.  You can scale them as suits you.

Let $\{e_i\}_{i=1}^{n-1} \cup \{v/|v|\}$ be an orthonormal basis for $n$-dimensional space.  (This is relatively easy.  Pick any basis.  If $v$ is parallel to a basis vector, renumber them so that one is last.  Otherwise, replace any of them with $v/|v|$ and apply [Gram-Schmidt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gram%E2%80%93Schmidt_process).)  Pick a collection of latitudes $\{u_i\}_{i=1}^m$ uniformly distributed over $(0, \pi)$.  Pick a collection of longitudes [uniformly](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Mathematica/Uniform_Spherical_Distribution) from the $n-1$-sphere, $\{\vec{w}_i\}_{i=1}^m$ (in the vector space spanned by $\{e_i\}_{i=1}^{n-1}$).  Your sample unit vectors are 
$$ \sin(u_i) \vec{w}_i + \cos(u_i) \frac{v}{|v|}  \text{.}  $$

Comment: Works great, thanks! I didn't specify what to do with magnitudes because I suspected that there would be freedom in how to pick them. Is it not true that the samples generated using this process are "random over every dimension"? They are still random in some sense though aren't they?

Comment: "Random over every dimension" really sounds like a product distribution, with independent distributions in each dimension.  We can't do that if we add a relation.  However, these can come from anywhere on the $n$-sphere, so they are "random over every dimension" in the sense that the support of the distribution is the largest set it could be.