# Are two correlated vectors in high dimension orthogonal?

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, discrete-mathematics, vector-spaces, mathematical-physics

I know the proof for two random vectors$\def\a{\mathbf{a}} \def\b{\mathbf{b}}  \def\c{\mathbf{c}}$ (say $\a$ and $\b$) in high dimension becomes orthogonal, i.e. $\langle \a,\b\rangle = 0$. I am keen to know what happens when $\a$ and $\b$ are correlated. Can they be quasi-orthogonal? In that case, how would be the inner product be defined?

Clarification: I am following the proof shown [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/995678/645496). The statement clearly says that both the vectors are randomly drawn (as a result I assume there is no correlation involved). But in my case, I have $\|\a−\c\|_2=\|\b\|_2.$ Now, I want to know whether in high dimension, $\a$ and $\b$ can be treated as orthonormal or not. Can this be proven that they are orthogonal (if they are)?

Comment: How are $a,\,b,\,c$ sampled so that $a-c$ has the same length as $b$? I'll update my answer once I understand the assumed joint distribution of $a,\,b$.

Comment: You can consider **a** as an original signal and **c** as a reconstructed signal (consider reconstructed using OMP-based algorithm). **b** can be treated as reconstruction error. So, all three vectors would have same length.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $a=c+b$ and $c\cdot b=0$, $a\cdot b=b^2\ge0$ and $a\cdot c=c^2\ge0$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am trying to follow the answer given [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/995678/645496). The statement clearly says that both the vectors are randomly drawn (as a result I assume there is no correlation involved). But in my case, I have $||\mathbf{a} - \mathbf{c}||_2 = ||\mathbf{b}||_2$. Now, I want to know whether in high dimension, **a** and **b** can be treated as orthonormal or not. Can this be proven that they are orthogonal (if they are)?

Comment: @God_Help See edit.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have some difficulty in understanding why did you write $c • b =0$? Are you considering orthogonality between them?

Comment: @God_Help See the third bullet point [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matching_pursuit#Properties).

Comment: That helps. Thanks a lot for the answer.